# Converting Tensorflow Lite Model to Tensorflow Model

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite, tensorflow.js

Is there's any way to convert a Tensorflow Lite model to a normal Tensorflow Model that i can use with Tensorflow.Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not supported by tfjs official converters as this is considered one-way conversion. but this tool is pretty amazing, although not the easiest to setup: https://github.com/PINTO0309/tflite2tensorflow